Trigger the keyboard IME via javascript
I am trying to build a visual/virtual (HTML/CSS/JS) keyboard and need to handle IME because of Chinese.

If I change the value of the input, IME is not showing
If I fire a KeyboardEvent keydown, IME is not showing

IME only shows when I am focused on the input and use the physical keyboard.
https://jsfiddle.net/5xw0mrs6/1/
Does somebody have a way to do it?
(I need it to work at least on chrome)
